# I am getting internal server error dont konw reason for that

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

my code.....this was controller

controller

```
@Getmapping("/Transferabalance/{id}")
public List<Transaction> transfer(@PathVariable("Accbalance") long Accbalance) throws ResourceNotFoundException
      {
           List<Transaction> balance=Transservice.findByAccbalance(Accbalance);
           if(balance==null)
                  throw new ResourceNotFoundException("NO BALANCE");
          else 
          return balance;
       }
```

This was service service

```
    public List<Transaction> findByAccbalance(long Accbalance) 
     {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           return transrepo.findByAccbalance(Accbalance);
     }
```

transaction repository i used an query to retrive the elemnt from data base

```
    public interface TransactionRepository extends CrudRepository<Transaction,Long>
    {
           @Query(value="select ACCBALANCE from TRANSACTION",nativeQuery = true)
           List<Transaction> findByAccbalance(long Accbalance);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1st of all, ***CrudRepository*** itself provides you lots of methods to perform operation then why use JPQL though your query is simple.

you can simply use findByAccbalance(long Accbalance) that will return you expected result in your case.

```
 List<Transaction> findByAccbalance(long Accbalance);
```

but if you wanna use Query then can you check with below Query:--

```
@Query(value="select c from TRANSACTION c")
           List<Transaction> findByAccbalance(long Accbalance);
```

Comment: iam getting org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "C" not found; SQL statement: